Is there a way to change the location of a trigger for a specific table in ssms?
By default when we create a trigger is located under the associated table in a foler called Triggers , I need to change this location? Is it Possible ?


... when we create a trigger is located under the associated table in a folder called Triggers

If you've ever looked at a plain, SQL dump of any database, you'll see that the Folder "structure" that you see in Management Studio is, largely, an Abstraction; a more "sensible" way to represent the mish-mash of stuff that's actually in the database.
It makes sense to have the Triggers that apply to a Table appear below that Table in this structure.
As per the "Principal of Least Surprise", every other SqlServer DBA on the planet will expect Triggers on a Table to be listed below that Table.  You risk great confusion by ignoring or changing this convention (not that I even think you can).

I need to change this location.

Why do you want to do so?
